# Setting up a cron job that does a chmod/chown

Tags: permissions, cron, mac-osx-server

I would like to set up a cron job that recusively does a chmod/chown on a directory (the dropbox directory).

This works when I execute the commands manually like:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/Dropbox
sudo chmod -R u+rw ~/Dropbox
```

I tried to convert it into a cron job like this:

```
10      *       *       *       *       sudo chown -R $USER ~/Dropbox
```

But it doesn't seem to do the job.

How to do this?

Comment: `incron` + `inotify` would be cleaner solutions :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want your root cron script (edit by running `sudo crontab -e`) to be:

```
 55 * * * * /bin/chown -R somename /home/somename/Dropbox && /bin/chmod u+rw /home/somename/Dropbox
```

Assuming the user is named `somename` and that `/home/somename/Dropbox` is the full path of your Dropbox directory.  As root user, ~ goes to `/root`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! I think this shows me some of the missing links I was looking for. I'll test it first thing tomorrow :)

Comment: Tested it, and it's working!

Comment: Great; glad its working.  The lessons are (a) don't expect environmental variables like `$PATH` to be defined equivalent to those of a signed in user in a cronjob (e.g., on my linuxbox $HOME is defined, but $PATH is set to `/usr/bin` and `/bin` from crontab and $USER is not defined; so in this case you didn't need to specify `/bin` before chmod/chown), (b) avoid `sudo` in scripts (run cron task as `root` user), (c) as root user `$HOME` will refer to /root not your normal user, (d) `~` should be avoided in cron scripts (by default run as `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: I'd also recommend putting in a script per David's advice if you ever do anything more complicated than this; a script seems overkill for a combination of a chmod / chown.  However, if you begin applying to other users's Dropboxes or other directories or decide to only run on recently changed files (e.g., result of `find`), etc than it makes sense to put in a script.

Answer (score 17):

`sudo` should *almost* ***never*** be used in scheduled tasks.  It expects to be able to talk to a terminal, and requires specific flags to avoid trying to do so.

Create your cron job as root (in `/etc/crontab` - Note that the format of this file is slightly different:  `minute hour    mday    month   wday`***`user`***`command`) instead.
This also has the benefit of working on systems where `sudo` isn't installed.

Comment: Thanks! I created this, but I'm still unsure about it. I didn't get the expected result:

`55 * * * * root chown -R somename ~/Dropbox`

Comment: `somename` could be anywhere; it is a relative path. Secondly, `~` is only understood by the shell; use `$HOME`. Use a command like this: `chown -R /some/path/somename $HOME/Dropbox` (this will use `root`'s home directory...)

Comment: @David: `somename` is not a path, but the user name (and should also contain the group name: `somename:somegroup`) ;)

Comment: @tvgemert What David said above (and in his answer) regarding paths/relative paths/symbolic paths (`~`) is ***CRITICALLY IMPORTANT*** -- Please spend some time with the cron and crontab man pages and be sure you understand what's going on (if in doubt, create a cron job that does `echo "what you want to do" > /tmp/what-i-would-run` and look at the results to be sure they're sane -- MUCH less chance of destroying the universe.)

Comment: Thank for the useful tips, gave me more insight already!

Answer (score 6):

Two issues:

1) Paths aren't normally set up in cron the same way they are when you log in. Try /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chown ... (or whatever the right paths are to those programs on your system).

2) sudo normally asks for your password, or may otherwise not be happy running noninteractively. I suggest you put the commands in root's crontab without the sudo instead, then the commands run as root.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple issues with your crontab:

```
10 * * * sudo chown -R $USER ~/Dropbox
```

The issues:

- `sudo` should not be used here; it requires terminal input
- `chown` should be fully specified (i.e., `/bin/chown`)
- `USER` as an actual variable may not exist; some systems use `LOGNAME`
- `~` (tilde) will only be recognized by a shell - a bare `chown` will not understand it
- specifying HOME in root's crontab goes to root's home

I think I'd actually script it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# FILE: /usr/local/bin/myscript

USER=$1
eval chown -R $1 ~$1/Dropbox
eval chmod -R u+rw ~$1/Dropbox
```

(The `eval` is needed to convert `~$1` to `~user` *then* to `/home/user`.)

Run this script from root's crontab:

```
# root's crontab
10 * * * /usr/local/bin/myscript someuser
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might be able to [enable ACL support](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#ACLs) and use setfacl to achieve the same/similar result.